# Pull 4 table rows from MySQL table and display with PHP on a page?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to simply Pull 4 table rows from MySQL table and display with PHP on a page? Can someone help me with this code... All I have is:

```
include_once ('db.php');

$link = mysql_connect($db,$user,$pass) or die("Can't connect to Database");
mysql_select_db($table,$link);

/* Main */
$query="SELECT * FROM $subtable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

HTML

```
<?php echo mysql_result('tablerow'); ?>
```

Comment: You need to loop through he results. If you want 4 rows then use `LIMIT 4`. Consult the [php mysql documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#example-1664) for a plethora examples of looping through a result set. Also you really shouldnt use the `mysql_*` functions for new development or learning. Use [`PDO`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`Mysqli`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead... they also have a plethora of looping examples.

Comment: +1 for good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that should get you started!

```
$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass,$table);

$loop = mysql_query($link,"SELECT * FROM $subtable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop))
{
 echo $row['yourrow']."<br/>";
}

mysql_close($link);
```

Just replace `yourrow` with the name of the row that you want to print out! Don't forget to set the variables `$host` `$user` `$pass` and `$table`